# Передача состояниа checkbox с ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Всем доброго дня суток
из ajax в пчп обработчик передаю дааные методом:
var selectval_1 = $(".select_1 option:selected").val();
и все раотает отличн, но в случае с checkbox при люом состоянии возврашает "on"
var check_test_stat_1 = $(".check_test_1 check_1:checked").val();
Подскажите где я ошибаюсь? Спасио заранее

Comment: пробовал и var selectval_1 = $(".select_1 input:checked").val(); но так возврашает ошыбку

Comment: какую ошыбку возврашает?

Comment: если вы `value` у `checkbox` вручную никак не меняете, то значение не поменяется. Если вам нужно узнать чекнут ли чекбокс попробуйте так `$(".check_test_1 check_1").is(":checked")` или `$(".check_test_1 check_1").prop("checked")`

Comment: Добброго времени суток. спасибо за ответ. По прежнему работает не коректно. в моем вариента и при включонном и при выкюченном флажке возврашает "on". Когда код изменил на ваш вариант (первый вариант кода) возврашает "false"  и при включонном и при выкюченном флажке.

Comment: полный код выглядит так: `$(document).ready(function(){ $('#form_pay_up_1').click(function(){
var select_text_1 = $(".select_1 option:selected").val();
var check_test_stat_1 = $(".check_test_1").val();

$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "$url/test.php", data: {
 select_1 : select_text_1,
 check_test_1 : check_test_stat_1
}
}).done(function(data){
$("#pay_up_content_1").html(data); }); }); });`

Comment: Vladimir, ваш код заработал.. из за моей опечатки вы тоже наверна механически вставили его.. Спасибо огромное! Рабочий код: `$(".check_test_1").is(":checked");` . Спасибо!!!

Comment: Vladimir, как я могу отметить ваш ответ как правильный? Я здесь новичок, на ваш коментари меня только флажок показывает.. Хочу поблагодарить как принято здес. Спасибо Vladimir